Getting Name from PermissionSetTabSetting

Let's say we want to get Name from PermissionSetTabSetting
List<PermissionSetTabSetting> targetPSTV = new List<PermissionSetTabSetting>();
    for(PermissionSetTabSetting pstv : [SELECT id, name, 
                                            visibility 
                                        FROM PermissionSetTabSetting 
                                        WHERE ParentId = :currentSourceId]) {
        PermissionSetTabSetting tv = new PermissionSetTabSetting();
        tv.name = pstv.name;
        tv.visibility = pstv.visibility;
        tv.parentId = currentTargetId;   
        system.debug('SObject:' + ptv.tab);
        system.debug('tab vis:' + ptv.visibility);
        targetPSTV.add(tv);
    }

but everytime we get id instead of real Name. What are we doing wrong?
P.S. Developer console in query editor returns back real names even thought we didn't set Tooling API

Where in your code do see the ID value in the Name field?  Where have you placed are your debug statements?  This code runs corrrectly in execute anonymous:  List<PermissionSetTabSetting> theList = [SELECT Id, Name, Visibility, ParentId FROM PermissionSetTabSetting]; System.debug('### ' + theList);

Did you check name field value?

Of course.  It correctly returned the Name values.  Did you run the select and debug in execute anonymous?
